# Django selecting data from model according to other model

Tags: python, django, model

i've got django database where is model X with attribute ManyToManyField(Y). Right now I need to select all the data from all the Y which are not related to one selected X. How can I do this by using database and not algorithm? I've used for-cycle but I would like to use more effective and advanced way.

Thanks.

/SOLVED

For situation when there is no relation from Y to X, I found that most efficient is to use command like

```
X.objects.exclude((parameter_of_Y)__in=[element.parameter_of_Y for element in elements])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) with the following query:

```
x = X.objects.get(...)
non_x_ys = Y.objects.exclude(y_m2n_field=x)
```

You can just provide the instance or its pk for such a query. See [the docs on m2m relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Thanks a lot for fast response